# How can I keep my DOM lightweight when appending arrays.Is there a way to delete the previously appended array or refresh the component?

Tags: reactjs

I need help with my interval scroll behavior component. I have a dummy array with a length of 10 items in my component. The container height is set to 200px, and each item has a height of 40px. According to this setup, only 5 items are visible at a time in the browser. After an interval of 3 seconds, it scrolls up, and the next set of items (5 to 10) is displayed. The desired behavior is to make it run in a loop. To achieve this, I append the same array as a new array when it reaches the last item (5 to 10), continuously showing a scrolling behavior.
The issue I'm facing is that when I append the array, it adds items to the DOM cumulatively. For example, after the initial 10 items, when I append, it shows 20, then 40, and so on, making the DOM bulky. I want to ensure that after appending the array, it deletes the previous data and only shows the new data. So, in the DOM, it should display only 10 items each time. I'm considering refreshing the component after appending the array. What would be the most suitable behavior? Additionally, are there any other logical approaches to handle this, considering that I handle my DOM, and I want the scroll behavior to continue in a loop without updating items on the DOM continuously."

Here's my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const visibleItems = Math.floor(containerHeight / itemHeight);
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentIndex + visibleItems >= items.length - visibleItems) {
        setItems((prevItems) => {
          const result = [...prevItems, ...items];
          return result;
        });
      }
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + visibleItems) % items.length);
    }, intervalDuration);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [items, currentIndex, containerHeight, itemHeight, items.length, intervalDuration]);
```